# Where does the pip3 downloads the .whl files in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-16.04

I have tried to install PyTorch using `pip3 install` command.
It downloaded the 636 MB file of .whl type.
Because I did not use `sudo` , installation did not proceed.
Now I do not want to download that file again. Where can I find that file in Ubuntu directory?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxXjV.png)

```
pip3 install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu100/torch-1.0.1.post2-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
Collecting torch==1.0.1.post2 from https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu100/torch-1.0.1.post2-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
Downloading https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu100/torch-1.0.1.post2-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl (636.8MB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 636.8MB 70kB/s 
Installing collected packages: torch
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch-1.0.1.post2.dist-info'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Comment: Now I'm genuinely curious where this defaults to, though you may need to be prepared to do the download again, but use [`pip download`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_download/) instead to save it to a location you desire.

Comment: From the next time, I will use it `pip download`, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I am not able to find the path of those downloaded files, but I am able to install the already Downloaded file of PyTorch using the command
 `pip3 install --user https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu100/torch-1.0.1.post2-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl`

It has extracted the files from some Download Cache.
So no need to worry about downloading again.

```
Collecting torch==1.0.1.post2 from 
https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu100/torch-1.0.1.post2-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl

Using cached 
https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu100/torch-1.0.1.post2-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl

Installing collected packages: torch
Successfully installed torch-1.0.1.post2
```

Comment: huh. interesting